# Excel vba if cell value is included in another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have worksheets called '1Q FY 18' which is the second sheet and 'Holiday' which is the 7th sheet.

The row 12 of '1Q FY 18' contains dates from 4/1 to 6/30.
And the cells from 'B20' to 'B35' contains holidays of 2018.

I would like to highlight columns in the second sheet that have matching value at range("B20:B35"). In other words, I would like to color the columns that is holiday.

My code was like this.

```
   Sub Holiday()
    lastr = Worksheets(2).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    lastc = Worksheets(2).UsedRange.Columns.Count
    Worksheets(2).Activate
    Set ws7 = Worksheets("Holiday")
    Set rng1 = ws7.Range("B20:B35")
    For i = 15 To lastc
    If Not IsEmpty(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(12, i).Value, rng1, 1)) Then
    Range(Cells(13, i), Cells(lastr - 2, i)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
    Next i
    End Sub
```

But error occurs with this one.
When I debug, it highlights

****If Not IsEmpty(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(12, i).Value, rng1, 1)) Then****

What do I do?

Comment: What is `lastc`?  You don't define `lastc`.

Comment: why not conditional formatting with networkdays.intl?

Comment: If the value is not found in `rng1` then it will error, not return an empty object, and stop the code.  You will need to deal with that error.  There are many answers on this site on how to deal with that.

Comment: @ScottCraner I tried using 'IsError' but it still won't work. Could you point me in a right direction?

Comment: @PaichengWu I just did

Comment: use iserror but on `Application.Vlookup` drop the `WorksheetFunction`, but as I said a quick search will give other methods.

Comment: @ScottCraner Call me a rookie, but I've been searching all day and I haven't found anyone who's having similar problems. Also I tried your method, and the error went away but it still wouldn't do what I ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple macro that does what you describe. I've placed a `.select` statement in it so you can step through the code to see how it works, but you should remove it after that. Once you understand how it works you can change to suit your needs. Let me know if you have questions. The animated gif shows each sheet of the workbook and then the macro running. In my example I've just chosen every week for the holidays, but you can change that. I also included a sub to reset the colors conveniently. (You say you want to "color the columns" but I just colored the cells.  If you really want to color the whole column you would replace `cell.interior`.. and `r.interior`... with `Columns(cell.Column).interior`...)

```
Sub test()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, cell As Range, holidayCell As Range
Set sh1 = Worksheets("1Q FY 18")
Set sh2 = Worksheets("Holiday")
Set r1 = sh1.Range("A12")
Set r1 = sh1.Range(r1, r1.End(xlToRight))
Set r2 = sh2.Range("B20:B35")
resetColor r1
For Each cell In r1
  cell.Select
  For Each holidayCell In r2
    If cell = holidayCell Then
      cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
Next cell
End Sub

Sub resetColor(r As Range)
    With r.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: First off, thanks for such a nice description. It helped me a LOT!! But the thing is that I have to highlight the columns starting from the one row below the cell that has the date. That's why I couldn't use 'For Each' command. Any other ideas??

Comment: The way to "thank" on StackOverflow is to click the up arrows or better yet, if you feel your question is answered, the check mark. If you want to highlight starting from one row below the date that can easily be done -- but do you want to color ALL cells below that?

Comment: If you do want to color ALL cells below the date cells then after the line: "If cell = holidayCell Then" put these 2 lines: "Columns(cell.Column).Interior.Color = vbYellow" & "resetColor sh1.Range(cell, cell.End(xlUp))"

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This was my first time actually posting on SO. I would like to highlight cells only until the last row used. that's why I used 'lastr'.

Comment: I think you mean you want to highlight the cell below the date and then continuing downward until just before a blank cell is reached. If so, this code will color those cells:  sh1.Range(cell.offset(1,0), cell.end(xlDown)).Interior.Color = vbYellow"